# The external modification/updation in app.config, web.config would be applicable at run-time?

Tags: configuration, app-config

Here is a doubt.

The external modification/updation in application configuration files for .net - app.config, web.config - would be applicable at run-time? Or the application need to be restarted.?

Is this applicable for the sections in these config files?

thanks
123Developer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, changes to the config files are reflected at runtime when you're not in debug mode.  So, a restart is not necessary.